# State is changing but colors are not changing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";

import LoginPage from "./Dashboard/Login";

class App extends Component {
  state = { darkState: false };

  render() {
    const { darkState } = this.state;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider
        theme={darkState ? this.props.darkTheme : this.props.theme}
      >
        <div className="App">
          <Switch
            checked={darkState}
            onChange={() => this.setState({ darkState: !darkState })}
          />
          <LoginPage />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When it is clicked switch for the first time, the color changes but does not return again.

I see that when I look at the console log it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to Material UI, theme props type is object or func

link [document](https://v3.material-ui.com/api/mui-theme-provider/)